# How to display an Image in a tableview using Swift and parse.com

Tags: ios, image, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to query images to my cells from Parse and then to the view controller when that cell is clicked on. I did have this working before the recent update with Swift and now I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI
import Bolts

class ProductTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        // Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.parseClassName = "Products"
        self.textKey = "productName"
        self.imageKey =  "productImage"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false

    }



    // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Products")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        return query
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! Customcells!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = Customcells(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        if let ProductName = object?["ProductName"] as? String {
            cell.ProductName.text = ProductName
        }


        // Display product image
      let initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question2")
        cell.productImage.image? = initialThumbnail!
        if let thumbnail = object?["ProductImage"] as? PFFile {
            cell.productImage.file = thumbnail
            cell.productImage.loadInBackground()
        }



        return cell
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        let productView = segue.destinationViewController as! ProductViewController

        // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller.
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let row = Int(indexPath.row)
            productView.currentObject = (objects?[row] as! PFObject)



        }
    }

}
```

This is the code for my one view controller that has the tableView on it. The images aren't showing up but everything else comes up. The product name shows in the correct spot and when the cell is clicked on it brings you to the view controller showing you the product description, product name, ect. The only thing not showing up is the image. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what I needed to do

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath      indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Customcells


    let imageFile = object?.objectForKey("ProductImage") as? PFFile
    cell.productImage.image = UIImage(named: "question2")
    cell.productImage.file = imageFile
    cell.productImage.loadInBackground()


    return cell

}
```

If you are using Parse as your backend this is the updated swift code for Xcode 7.1 that you can use to pull your images into a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :

```
 let profileImage:PFFile = Places[indexPath.row]["Image"] as! PFFile
 profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?)-> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                cell.pic.setImage(UIImage(data: imageData!)!, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for helping but you can help me figure out what of my code would go where in this? sorry I'm just fairly new to parse and swift